Does taking Guru Diksha reduce our life troubles / sin by 50%?
Does taking Guru Diksha reduce our life troubles / sin by 50%?
To what extent can taking Guru Diksha be seen as a transformative experience that helps in alleviating life troubles and reducing the impact of sins, and what are the spiritual, psychological, and practical factors that contribute to this belief?
